# Mysql query for matching month and year

Tags: php, mysql

I have form with 4 fields namely(start month, start year, end month, end year)
and MySQL table structure is like id, customer id, amount,  month, year

Now, I need to display the rows with matching condition as between the start month and year and end month and year.

I tried this query

```
select id,customer id,concat(month,'-',year) as d1 from payroll where
empid='$_POST[emp_id]' and (STR_TO_DATE(d1,'%m-%Y') between
STR_TO_DATE('$_POST[fmonth]-$_POST[fyear]','%m-%Y') and
STR_TO_DATE('$_POST[tmonth]-$_POST[tyear]','%m-%Y'))
```

Please advise....

Comment: Uhm, whatever you do, DONT use $_POST like this. It's an open door to SQL-Injection!!!

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? He's obviously a beginner, so help rather than demoralize him.

Comment: That's not a query. That looks like a (fragment) of PHP code that is indented to create a query. Please paste your actual query as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the columns `year` and `month` and the 4 form fields are integers, this would work:

```
SELECT id
     , customer id
     , CONCAT(month, '-', year) AS d1 
FROM payroll 
WHERE empid = '$_POST[emp_id]' 
  AND (year, month) >= ( '$_POST[fyear]', '$_POST[fmonth]' ) 
  AND (year, month) <= ( '$_POST[tmonth]', '$_POST[tyear]' )
```

---

You should probably take care of those `$_POST[]` before sending them to the database for security reasons (SQL injection).

A compound index on `(empid, year, month)` would help performance.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine.. Also to protect SQL injection to use addslashes comment ?

Comment: Start by reading this: [PHP and prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)